# Need QRegEx logic to split number bullet

Tags: qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

I am trying to build a QRegEx logic to split number bullet. I tried but couldn't succeed.

sample code:

```
    QString query("1. Ravi Gupta.Pari.Paagal");
    QStringList list = query.split(QRegularExpression("\\(.*?\\)"));
    qDebug()<<"Output: "<<list;
```

I am using QRegEx first time. Looking for some help here.

Sample text is --> "1. Ravi Gupta.Pari.Paagal"

Required output should be --> "Ravi Gupta.Pari.Paagal"       (without number bullet)

Comment: You say `"I tried but couldn't succeed"`: you should show what you've tried so far -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my question with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `QString::split`.  If the intention is simply to obtain that part of the line after the numbered bullet you could use something like...

```
QString text("1. Ravi Gupta.Pari.Paagal");
QRegularExpression re("^\\d+\\.\\s+(.*)$");
if (auto match = re.match(text); match.hasMatch()) {
    std::cout << "found match [" << match.captured(1) << "]\n";
}
```

Should give...

> found match [Ravi Gupta.Pari.Paagal]